# Angular 4 default child route Not working

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular4-router

I have angular 4 project with following structure:

```
src
|- app
|  |- home
|  |  |- home.component.ts/html/scss
|  |  |- home.module.ts
|  |  |- home.routing.ts
|  |  |- products
|  |  |  |- products.component.ts/html/scss
|- app.component.ts/html/scss
|- app-routing.module.ts
|- app.module.ts
```

My `app.routing.module.ts` file contains following:

```
const routes: Route[] = [
{
    path: "home", component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AppAuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: AppConstants.ROUTE_LOGIN, pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: false})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

and `home.routing.ts` contains following child routs:

```
{
path: "home",
component: HomeComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HomeStatsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'products',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: ProductsComponent
      }
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddProductComponent
      }
    ]
  },
 ]
}
```

In home.module.ts child routs has been imported using `RouterModule.forChild(HomeRoutes)`. And there is a router outlet for the child routes in home.component.html. All the routes except for default child route (`http://localhost:4200/home`) works successfully (`http://localhost:4200/home/products` works fine). `http://localhost:4200/home` give out no errors, it just shows empty white space because router outlet is empty. But if I define default child route of home component in `app.module.ts` it works fine. What did I did wrong for it to not work?

Comment: What are the contents of HomeStatsComponent? do you mind mentioning those too? you have set your 'home' route to it but it is not listed in the project structure

Comment: Try `http://localhost:4200/home/home` what does it shows?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/home'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix the issue by lazy loading syntax which is `loadChildren`. and removing the first level configuration. Before that I needed to restructure the code little bit to export the home routing module and import is to home module. Changed file are as below:

`home.routing.ts`:

```
const homeRoutes: Route[] = [
{
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HomeStatsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'products',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: ProductsComponent
      }
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddProductComponent
      }
    ]
  },
]
}
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

Then `app.routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Route[] = [
{
    path: "home", component: HomeComponent,  loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
  },
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: false})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

And importing `HomeRoutingModule` at `home.module.ts`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try by removing the first level configuration directly like. As you have already routed it to `home`, it is finding the `/home` in the `/home` route, so according to the configuration it become `http://localhost:4200/home/home`

```
 [ 
   {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HomeStatsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'products',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: ProductsComponent
      }
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddProductComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that when I remove the first level routing child routing will not work.

Comment: But your answer helped me to figure out the issue. Thank you